# Is "I have checked today" correct?

Tags: grammar

I checked if I had money in my bank account or not an hour ago.

Now if I say "I have checked today my bank account", is that a correct sentence.

Should it be "I have checked" or "I checked it today"

Comment: What have you found already? I'm sure this site already has questions that would help.

Comment: You're looking for past simple / past perfect tense

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match anything in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly wrong word order "*I have checked my bank account today*" is correct.
If the listener knows you are talking about your bank account then "*I have checked it today*" is fine.

Comment: *I have checked today*, as per the title of the question, can also be correct. (Although, confusingly, the body of the question doesn't match that title.)